# No route matches [POST] "/coachings/4" when trying to use Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy

```
        coachings GET    /coachings(.:format)                        {:action=>"index", :controller=>"coachings"}
                  POST   /coachings(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"coachings"}
     new_coaching GET    /coachings/new(.:format)                    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"coachings"}
    edit_coaching GET    /coachings/:id/edit(.:format)               {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"coachings"}
         coaching GET    /coachings/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"coachings"}
                  PUT    /coachings/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"coachings"}
                  DELETE /coachings/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"coachings"}
```

my routes are correct, here is my view index

<%= link_to 'Destroy', coaching, :confirm 'Are you sure?', :method => :destroy %>

here is my controller

```
def destroy
    @coaching = Coaching.find(params[:id])
    @coaching.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to coachings_path }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
end
```

any ideas why i get this error? i'm new to RoR this is my first projects i've done by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:delete` method

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', coaching, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Delete: the GET action where you get the "Are you sure?" Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In your `link_to` you are using a method of `destroy` which isn't a valid HTTP verb so Rails is probably defaulting to `POST`. You'll need to use `DELETE` instead:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', coaching, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```